# Undo a user's folder changes

Tags: 2013, content-and-structure

A user on my system just went nuts moving files and creating new folders. 
I want to undo it because now there are a bunch of broken links to files that refer to paths that no longer exist.

Is there any way to roll back the file structure by a few hours? or undo a certain user's actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a site backup to restore from, no, there is no undo option like that.